# How to install the Python bitcoin module on windows for presale wallet import?

Tags: presale, password, python

I've been holding Ethereum since the pre-sale. I want to continue to just hold my presale wallet because its safe as cold storage (rather than importing into my wallet).

However, I want to be able to check that I still remember my password to my wallet.

There are instructions to do so here: [Ether Purchase Troubleshooting](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/07/23/ether-purchase-troubleshooting/) posted by Vitalik Buterin on July 23rd, 2014.

I am a first time Python user, ran Python 2.7.11 and received message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File
"C:\Eth\pyethsaletool-master\pyethsaletool.py", line 9, in <module>
from bitcoin import * ImportError No module named Bitcoin
```

So this means that i'm supposed to load the python Bitcoin module. I'm not certain how to do this.

That said, I installed or rather should I say I upgraded pip:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Now this is where I really am not sure what/how to do next:

I tried to install [python-bitcoinlib](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib) and received a compatibility error
so next I went to [pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools) and typed:

```
c:\Python27\python.exe C:\Eth\pybitcointools-master\setup.py
```

I received the following error:

```
error: no commands supplied
```

*Note: I didn't configure Python to seamless work with my Command prompt which is why I am using python.exe command.*

not sure what to do next... What to try do next?

Comment: what happens if you run `c:\Python27\python.exe C:\Eth\pybitcointools-master\setup.py install` ? (note the "install")

Comment: running install   
running bdist_egg  
running egg_info  
creating bitcoin.egg_info  
writing bitcoin.egg_info\PKG-INFO  
writing top-level names to bitcoin.egg-info\top_level.txt  
writing dependency_links to bitcoin.egg.info\dependency_links.txt  
writing manifest file 'bitcoin.egg-info\SOURCES.tct'  
**warning: maifest_maker: standard file 'setup.py' not found  

error: package directory 'bitcoin' does not exist**

Comment: Have you tried just running `pip install bitcoin` ?

Comment: c:\Python\python.exe pip install bitcoin  
**can't open file 'pip' [errno 2] no such file or directory**                           also trying w/o exe command: pip install bitcoin   
**'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

Comment: The reason pip cannot be found is likely because you didn't configure, as you wrote, Python to seamlessly work from the command prompt. Please fix your Python installation and rerun pip.

Comment: I now can simply type Python at the command prompt to access Python (i.e. it is now a seamless experience by editing the path in System Properties / Environment Variables). Typing command: pip install bitcoin yeilds a syntax error